# InnerClass object being a member of OuterClass object is created twice

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have two classes: OuterClass and InnerClass. InnerClass is a private member of OuterClass and should be created in OuterClass constructor with an InnerClass(int) constructor, however the default InnerClass constructor is still called.

InnerClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef INNERCLASS_HPP_
#define INNERCLASS_HPP_

class InnerClass {
public:
    int a;
    InnerClass();
    InnerClass(int);
    ~InnerClass();
};

#endif /* INNERCLASS_HPP_ */
```

InnerClass.cpp:

```
#include "InnerClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

InnerClass::InnerClass() {
    a = 1;
    std::cout << "inner class constructed, a = " << a << std::endl;
}
InnerClass::InnerClass(int x) {
    a = x;
    std::cout << "inner class constructed, a = " << a << std::endl;
    //automatically: object InnerClass (a=3) is destroyed here...
}
InnerClass::~InnerClass() {
    std::cout << "inner class destructed, a = " << a << std::endl;
}
```

OuterClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef OUTERCLASS_HPP_
#define OUTERCLASS_HPP_

#include "InnerClass.hpp"

class OuterClass {
private:
    InnerClass blah;
public:
    OuterClass();
    ~OuterClass();
    void doSth();
};

#endif /* OUTERCLASS_HPP_ */
```

OuterClass.cpp:

```
#include "OuterClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

OuterClass::OuterClass() {
    // automatically: blah = InnerClass();
    std::cout << "outer class constructing started, blah.a = " << blah.a << std::endl;
    blah = InnerClass(3);
    std::cout << "outer class constructed" << std::endl;
}

OuterClass::~OuterClass() {
    std::cout << "outer class destructed" << std::endl;
}

void OuterClass::doSth() {
    std::cout << "doSth: " << blah.a << std::endl;
}
```

main:

```
#include "OuterClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Compiled at " << __TIME__ << std::endl;

    OuterClass x = OuterClass();
    x.doSth();

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
Compiled at 12:11:12
inner class constructed, a = 1 //this is unexpected
outer class constructing started, blah.a = 1 //this should be random data
inner class constructed, a = 3
inner class destructed, a = 3 //this is unexpected
outer class constructed
doSth: 3
done
outer class destructed
inner class destructed, a = 3
```

Questions:

1. Why is the default constructor of InnerClass called at the start of OuterClass constructor?
2. What and why is destructed in OuterClass constructor ("inner class destructed, a = 3 //this is unexpected")?
3. It seems that InnerClass object with a = 3 was destructed in the OuterClass constructor, than why does method doSth() return 3 instead of random data?
4. Why does removing an InnerClass() constructor (from both InnerClass.hpp and InnerClass.cpp files) result in compile-time error at the OuterClass constructor in OuterClass.cpp file? The error says that no InnerClass() definition found.

Comment: I think you should have used InnerClass *blah? Then there will not be any double-construction. InnerClass blah will automatically construct a local instance upon creation that you overwrite in the constructor. It pobably is destructed in the end (rather than becoming a mem leak (well, even those get clear once the app exits)) since it has local scope, once the whole object is deconstructed. --- BTW, is your code correct? blah = InnerClass(3);  should call for a new operator???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use initializer-list in constructor.

```
OuterClass::OuterClass() : blah(3) {
    // automatically: blah = InnerClass();
    std::cout << "outer class constructing started, blah.a = " << blah.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "outer class constructed" << std::endl;
}
```

Since when you use

```
OuterClass::OuterClass() {
    // automatically: blah = InnerClass();
    std::cout << "outer class constructing started, blah.a = " << blah.a << std::endl;
    blah = InnerClass(3);
    std::cout << "outer class constructed" << std::endl;
}
```

firstly for initialize blah will be called default c-tor and in `blah = InnerClass(3);`, that creates temporary object and copy it to blah, after this string will be called destructor of temporary object.

Comment: I do not really understand why it overrides the existing object with the new value of a equals 3. I would understand if there was "destructing object with a = 1".

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak in blah = InnerClass(3); operator = for InnerClass called, by default operator = copy values of members of object that stays at right-side of assignment to object that stays left-side of assignment and returns reference to *this (left-side of assignment object), when it returns, temporary object goes out of scope and destructed.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why is the default constructor of InnerClass called at the start of OuterClass constructor?

To construct `blah`.

> 2) What and why is destructed in OuterClass constructor ("inner class destructed, a = 3 //this is unexpected")?

The `InnerClass(3)` you constructed in the second line of the constructor. The one you used to hold the value you assigned to `blah`. It is destructed because it goes out of scope once the assignment to `blah` is complete.

> 3) It seems that InnerClass object with a = 3 was destructed in the OuterClass constructor, than why does method doSth() return 3 instead of random data?

Because you assigned the value `3` to `blah`. Your code reads;

`blah = InnerClass(3);`

This creates an InnerClass with the value 3 and then copies its value to `blah`. So both `blah` and this temporary object have the same value. The temporary is then destroyed.

If you think about it, there is no other sensible way to implement this line of code.

> 4) Why does removing an InnerClass() constructor (from both InnerClass.hpp and InnerClass.cpp files) result in compile-time error at the OuterClass constructor in OuterClass.cpp file? The error says that no InnerClass() definition found.

Because then you have no way to construct `blah` in the first place. (As others have pointed out, you probably wanted an initializer list to construct `blah` right in the first place rather than default constructing it and then having to go to contortions to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
OuterClass::OuterClass() /* default blah constructor is called here */ {
    std::cout << "outer class constructing started, blah.a = " << blah.a << std::endl;
    blah = InnerClass(3); /* a temporary InnerClass is created */
    std::cout << "outer class constructed" << std::endl;
} //temporary InnerClass destroyed (out of scope)
```

Use `initializer list` to prevent calling default constructor as ForEveR suggests

Answer (score 0):

1. When the constructor of OuterClass starts executing the body, all members must be constructed. Since there is a `blah` InnerClass member, it got constructed.
2. When you assign to `blah` in OuterClass::OuterClass(), there is a temporary instance created. Here's the order of things:

   - A temporary InnerClass(3) is constructed.
   - It is assigned to `blah`.
   - The temporary value is destructed -- that's why there's a destructor call.
3. Follows from 2: blah has a set to 3 in the assignment mentioned in #2 above.
4. One'd infer that in C++ if you have a specialized argument-taking constructors declared, the default constructor is not created behind your back by the compiler anymore. I can't bother to look into the relevant place in the standard right now, editors feel free to correct this one.

It'd have helped you if you instrumented InnerClass as follows:

1. Keep a static instance counter, and copy it to every instance. That way you'd know which instance is reporting things back.
2. Manually write `InnerClass & operator=(const InnerClass &)` to see when is it invoked.

Answer (score 0):

*(PS: Are you coming from Java World to C++ by any chance?)*

**Output explained:**

```
inner class constructed, a = 1 //this is unexpected
```

InnerClass is constructed with default constructor first

```
outer class constructing started, blah.a = 1 //this should be random data
```

This is the value of InnerClass constructed in previous step with default ctor

```
inner class constructed, a = 3
```

A temporary InnerClass is constructed with the overloaded ctor and assigned to the blah member (the implicit operator= is called - you can check by overloading the operator=)

```
inner class destructed, a = 3 //this is unexpected
```

The temporary InerClass created in the previous step is destroyed

```
outer class constructed
doSth: 3
done
outer class destructed
inner class destructed, a = 3
```

**Answers:**

*Why is the default constructor of InnerClass called at the start of
    OuterClass constructor?*

Because you have InnerClass member. You should make it a pointer or use initializer list.

```
OuterClass::OuterClass() 
: blah(3)
{
    // automatically: blah = InnerClass();
    std::cout << "outer class constructing started, blah.a = " << blah.a << std::endl;
    // blah = InnerClass(3);
    std::cout << "outer class constructed" << std::endl;
}
```

*What and why is destructed in OuterClass
    constructor ("inner class destructed, a = 3 //this is unexpected")?*

The temporary InnerClass is destroyed here.

*It seems that InnerClass object with a = 3 was destructed in the
    OuterClass constructor, than why does method doSth() return 3
    instead of random data?*

The blah member now has a copy of InnerClass object with value 3

*Why does removing an InnerClass()
    constructor (from both InnerClass.hpp and InnerClass.cpp files)
    result in compile-time error at the OuterClass constructor in
    OuterClass.cpp file? The error says that no InnerClass() definition
    found.*

You mean removing the default constructor. Yes, the error is expected because blah member is first created with default ctor.